# Convert From indy udp To Tcp

Tags: delphi, indy

i have been using indy udp and i want to move on to indy tcp

but i dont know how to convert the code to work in the same way with indy tcp

my  project work to send stream as chat room here is the udp code

```
procedure TForm1.recorderData(Sender: TObject; const Buffer: Pointer;
  BufferSize: Cardinal; var FreeIt: Boolean);
begin
Freeit :=True;
if IDUDPCLIENT.active then
IDUDPCLIENT.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(Buffer^, Buffersize))
else
stop.Caption := 'error';
end;
```

and this is the server on read event

```
procedure TForm1.UDPReceiverUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  AudioDataSize: Integer;
  AudioData : Pointer;
begin
  try
    EnterCriticalSection(Section);
    try
      AudioDataSize := Length(AData);
      if AudioDataSize > 10 then
      begin
        try
          if not Player.Active then
          begin
            Player.Active := True;
            Player.WaitForStart;
          end;
        except
        end;
        if BlockAlign > 1 then Dec(AudioDataSize, AudioDataSize mod BlockAlign);
        AudioData := AudioBuffer.BeginUpdate(AudioDataSize);
        try
          BytesToRaw(AData, AudioData^, AudioDataSize);
        finally
          AudioBuffer.EndUpdate;
        end;
      end else
      begin
        Player.Active := False;
        Player.WaitForStop;
      end;
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(Section);
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

how i make them work in the same way in indy tcp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indy's UDP and TCP components use different interface architectures.  It is not enough to just port the code, you have to re-design your communication protocol accordingly, which may require you to re-write your core code logic.  Remember that UDP is message-based, but TCP is not, so you have to design your own message framing.

You also have to take into account that like `TIdUDPServer`, `TIdTCPServer` is also multi-threaded.  But unlike `TIdUDPServer`, `TIdTCPServer` does not have a `ThreadedEvent` property, so you have to provide your own synchronizing when accessing other threads, especially the main UI thread.

Based on your simple example, try something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.recorderData(Sender: TObject; const Buffer: Pointer; BufferSize: Cardinal; var FreeIt: Boolean);
begin
  FreeIt := True;
  try
    if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
    begin
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(BufferSize);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(RawToBytes(Buffer^, BufferSize));
      Exit;
    end;
  except
  end;
  stop.Caption := 'error';
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  AudioDataSize: Integer;
  AudioDataBytes: TIdBytes;
  AudioData: Pointer;
begin
  AudioDataSize := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt();
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(AudioDataBytes, AudioDataSize);

  EnterCriticalSection(Section);
  try
    if AudioDataSize > 10 then
    begin
      try
        if not Player.Active then
        begin
          Player.Active := True;
          Player.WaitForStart;
        end;
      except
      end;
      if BlockAlign > 1 then Dec(AudioDataSize, AudioDataSize mod BlockAlign);
      AudioData := AudioBuffer.BeginUpdate(AudioDataSize);
      try
        BytesToRaw(AudioDataBytes, AudioData^, AudioDataSize);
      finally
        AudioBuffer.EndUpdate;
      end;
    end else
    begin
      Player.Active := False;
      Player.WaitForStop;
    end;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(Section);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank You remy thats helps me a lot.

Comment: one more thing remy iam trying to send message in udp i was doing this iDCLIENT.Broadcast(strMsg, 16000);  and read like this msg.Lines.Add(BytesToString(AData)); how to do it in tcp ?

Comment: TCP does not support broadcasting. You would have to send a separate copy of your message data to every individual TCP connection that you have.